# Import range from 3 sheets/tabs into 4th

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

I currently have 3 sheets (tabs) in a Google Sheets workbook. Each column header (Row 1) in the 3 sheets are identical. I'd like to create a 4th sheet that combines ALL the contents in the 3 sheets that looks like:

```
Sheet 1
Sheet 2
Sheet 3
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? If easier, I do not mind having the header show up 3 times.  Thank you.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
={'Sheet 1'!1:10000 ; 'Sheet 2'!1:10000 ; 'Sheet 3'!1:10000}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing. To confirm, create a 4th tab, and input this formula into cell A1? Throwing an error for me, the formula isn't populating anything. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps, depending on locale, you need to use comma instead of the semicolon. Please share a screenshot of your data, or a copy of your spreadsheet, if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

- join them as they are by creating the 4th sheet and pasting one of these formulas to **A1**:

  ```
  ={'Sheet 1'!A1:10000\ 'Sheet 2'!A1:10000\ 'Sheet 3'!A1:10000}
  ```




  ```
  ={'Sheet 1'!A1:10000; 'Sheet 2'!A1:10000; 'Sheet 3'!A1:10000}
  ```
- join them with **`QUERY()`** if header for all 3 sheets is the same:

  ```
  =QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:10000\ 'Sheet 2'!A2:10000\ 'Sheet 3'!A2:10000}; "select *"; 1)
  ```

  ```
  =QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:10000; 'Sheet 2'!A2:10000; 'Sheet 3'!A2:10000}, "select *", 1)
  ```
- join them by skipping empty rows (let's say if data are present column A is always populated):

  change **`"select *"`** to **`"select * where A is not null"`**